# PhpStorm comment settings per filetype

Tags: environment-variables, phpstorm, settings

In an actual PHP file when I use <kbd>Ctrl + /</kbd> it actually puts two slashes in front of the code as expected: `//`.

However in an **.env file** when I use <kbd>Ctrl + /</kbd> it will put a `;` in front of the code instead of the expected `#`.

My question is where this setting is placed in PhpStorm.

The version I use is PhpStorm 2022.3.3

Comment: 1) There are no options for choosing what comment symbol to use. They are predefined: 1 for end-of-line comments and one for blocks (multi line). 2) Either you are doing something wrong (most likely IMO) ... or it is because of the outdated IDE (latest version is 2023.3.4 -- 1 year/3 major versions newer). 3) The IDE cannot put `;` in `.env` files -- it's not valid comment symbol. That means that something is off / wrong.

Comment: So far it seems to me that you have the following: associated the `.env` files with the `INI config` file type (or some another one). Therefore I may suggest the following: 1) install the dedicated **.env files support** plugin 2) Make sure that your `.env` files are associated with a special **.env file** file type that this plugin provides.